# aws boto3 client Stubber help stubbing unit tests

Tags: python-2.7, boto, boto3

I'm trying to write some unit tests for aws RDS. Currently, the start stop rds api calls have not yet been implemented in moto. I tried just mocking out boto3 but ran into all sorts of weird issues. I did some googling and found http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/stubber.html

So I have tried to implement the example for rds but the code appears to be behaving like the normal client, even though I have stubbed it. Not sure what's going on or if I am stubbing correctly?

```
from LambdaRdsStartStop.lambda_function import lambda_handler
from LambdaRdsStartStop.lambda_function import AWS_REGION

def tests_turn_db_on_when_cw_event_matches_tag_value(self, mock_boto):
    client = boto3.client('rds', AWS_REGION)
    stubber = Stubber(client)
    response = {u'DBInstances': [some copy pasted real data here], extra_info_about_call: extra_info}
    stubber.add_response('describe_db_instances', response, {})

    with stubber:
        r = client.describe_db_instances()
        lambda_handler({u'AutoStart': u'10:00:00+10:00/mon'}, 'context')
```

so the mocking WORKS for the first line inside the stubber and the value of r is returned as my stubbed data. When I try and go into my lambda_handler method inside my lambda_function.py and still use the stubbed client it behaves like a normal unstubbed client:

lambda_function.py

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    rds_client = boto3.client('rds', region_name=AWS_REGION)
    rds_instances = rds_client.describe_db_instances()
```

error output:

```
  File "D:\dev\projects\virtual_envs\rds_sloth\lib\site-packages\botocore\auth.py", line 340, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError
NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Comment: The advantage of the stubber over a typical mock is that it behaves nearly exactly like a client minus making an actual http request. So you will need to still set up the client with credentials and configure the region or it will error out like that.

Comment: Hi Jordon, I think you may have misread my post. The mocking WORKS in my test until I try and initialise the client in another file -> lambda_function.py

Comment: You don't appear to be passing the stubbed client to your lambda handler.

Comment: No mate, it is not my intention to pass the stubbed client to anything. I'm trying to "override" the real client in lamnda_function.py with the stubbed client so i can run some unit tests. Kind of how you would with moto or python mock

Comment: you are correct though, I could pass the client into lambda_handler but this seems like a hacky way of doing it. Would be nice if anyone has any suggestions on a cleaner way fo doing it

Comment: The stubber only affects the client you initialize it with. You would need to use patch to impact every client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to patch boto3 where it is called in the routine that you will be testing. Also Stubber responses appear to be consumed on each call and thus will require another add_response for each stubbed call as below:

```
def tests_turn_db_on_when_cw_event_matches_tag_value(self, mock_boto):
    client = boto3.client('rds', AWS_REGION)
    stubber = Stubber(client)
    # response data below should match aws documentation otherwise more errors due to botocore error handling
    response = {u'DBInstances': [{'DBInstanceIdentifier': 'rds_response1'}, {'DBInstanceIdentifierrd': 'rds_response2'}]}

    stubber.add_response('describe_db_instances', response, {})
    stubber.add_response('describe_db_instances', response, {})

    with mock.patch('lambda_handler.boto3') as mock_boto3:
        with stubber:
            r = client.describe_db_instances() # first_add_response consumed here
            mock_boto3.client.return_value = client
            response=lambda_handler({u'AutoStart': u'10:00:00+10:00/mon'}, 'context')  # second_add_response would be consumed here
            # asert.equal(r,response)
```